# Regex validation: only allow specific values between curly brackets

Tags: regex, validation

Could some one help me with a regular expression that will allow only specific values between curly brackets:

```
This is some {text} with {value}
This {text} is not {allowed}
```

In this case only the values text and value are allowed. Any other value between the curly brackets should not be allowed. So first example is valid, while the second is not.
Also matching should be case insensitive.

Thanks!

Comment: 1- What language tool are you using? 2- What have you tried? 3- Should it match the whole sentence if there's no brackets? 4- Should it match the whole sentence if the brackets are valid, or should it just match the brackets?

Comment: @donerier did you want to match `This is some {textdffd} with {valuefdfd}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:[^}{]*{(?:text|value)})*[^}{]*$
```

Try this.See demo.Do not forget to set flags `i` , `g`,`m`.

http://regex101.com/r/yA5iD9/14

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'm using .net. I've tried your solution, but also {text1} is valid while it shouldn't. Also any other text that is not in brackets are not vaild while it should (this is {text} is not valid)

Comment: Ok, partially working now. "This is some {text} with {value} with some more words" is  not vaild while it should

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex,

```
^(?:[^{}]*\{(?:text|value)\})+[^{}]*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yA5iD9/11)